# My Javascript if statement returns true even though it is false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button and a form on my page. When the button is clicked it should display the form, and when click again it should hide the form.

For some reason, whenever the button is clicked it executes the first if statement regardless of whether it is true or not. How can I fix this?

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="return-user-signin">
    <h2 class="checkout-return-cust">Returning customer?</h2>
    <button class="checkout-login-button"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> log in</button>

    <form class="woocomerce-form woocommerce-form-login login check-login pop-login-form" method="post" style="display: none;">


        <p class="form-row form-row-first">
            <input placeholder="Username or email" class="input-text placeholder" name="username" id="username" type="text">
        </p>
        <p class="form-row form-row-last">
            <input class="input-text placeholder" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" type="password">
        </p>
        <div class="clear"></div>


        <p class="form-row">

        </p>

        <div class="clear"></div>


    </form>
```

Here is my JavaScript

```
var login_button = $(".checkout-login-button");
var login_form = $(".pop-login-form");

if (login_form.css('display') == "none") {
    $(document).on('click', '.checkout-login-button', function () {
        login_form.show();
        login_form.off('click');
        login_form.css('display', 'block');
        return;
    });
} else {
    $(document).on('click', '.checkout-login-button', function () {
        login_form.hide();
        login_form.off('click');
        login_form.css('display', 'none');
        return;
    });
}
```

Comment: An `if` statement doesn't "return" anything. Do you mean "the condition in my `if` statement evaluates to true even though it is false"?

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around, you define the `.click()` event once and inside it you define the logic for the `if-else` structure.

The way you have it now, it is only showing the form (never hiding it) because the only part of the code being run is the one inside `login_form.css('display') == "none"` which is true when the page loads

HIH

```js
var login_button = $(".checkout-login-button"); var login_form = $(".pop-login-form");

    
$(document).on('click', '.checkout-login-button', function(){
      if( login_form.css('display') == "none" ) {
      login_form.show();
       login_form.off('click');
        login_form.css('display', 'block');
        
      }

       else {
        login_form.hide();
        login_form.off('click');
        login_form.css('display', 'none');
          
            }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="return-user-signin">
    <h2 class="checkout-return-cust">Returning customer?</h2>
    <button class="checkout-login-button"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> log in</button>

    <form class="woocomerce-form woocommerce-form-login login check-login pop-login-form" method="post" style="display: none;">


<p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <input placeholder="Username or email" class="input-text placeholder" name="username" id="username" type="text">
</p>
<p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <input class="input-text placeholder" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" type="password">
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>


<p class="form-row">

</p>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have first to create the event, then inside it you do your conditional statements.

```js
var login_button = $(".checkout-login-button"); 
var login_form = $(".pop-login-form");

$(document).on('click', '.checkout-login-button', function(){
    if( login_form.css('display') == "none" ) {
        login_form.show();
        login_form.off('click');
        login_form.css('display', 'block');
        return;
    } else {
        login_form.hide();
        login_form.off('click');
        login_form.css('display', 'none');
        return;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="return-user-signin">
    <h2 class="checkout-return-cust">Returning customer?</h2>
    <button class="checkout-login-button"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> log in</button>

    <form class="woocomerce-form woocommerce-form-login login check-login pop-login-form" method="post" style="display: none;">


<p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <input placeholder="Username or email" class="input-text placeholder" name="username" id="username" type="text">
</p>
<p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <input class="input-text placeholder" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" type="password">
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>


<p class="form-row">

</p>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to change the function handling the click, which would be accomplished by removing the existing one and adding another. You’re trying to remove it here:

```
login_form.off('click');
```

but that doesn’t work when you actually added the listener to `document` to make use of event delegation, and no listener is being added again after this.

It’s simpler to just have one listener, and to attach it directly to the element if it exists at the time:

```
var login_form = $(".pop-login-form");

$(".checkout-login-button").click(function () {
    login_form.toggle();
});
```

which your `login_button` initialization suggests is the case. If not, continue with event delegation by all means:

```
var login_form = $(".pop-login-form");

$(document).on("click", ".checkout-login-button", function () {
    login_form.toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one `click` handler and check the CSS state inside it. Besides, `css` is taking care of the visibility using `display:block/none`, so in my opinion the `show()`/`hide()` methods are redundant.

```js
var login_button = $(".checkout-login-button");
var login_form = $(".pop-login-form");

$(document).on('click', '.checkout-login-button', function() {
  if (login_form.css('display') === "none") {
    login_form.css('display', 'block');
  } else {
    login_form.css('display', 'none');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="return-user-signin">
  <h2 class="checkout-return-cust">Returning customer?</h2>
  <button class="checkout-login-button"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> log in</button>

  <form class="woocomerce-form woocommerce-form-login login check-login pop-login-form" method="post" style="display: none;">


    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
      <input placeholder="Username or email" class="input-text placeholder" name="username" id="username" type="text">
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
      <input class="input-text placeholder" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" type="password">
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>


    <p class="form-row">

    </p>

    <div class="clear"></div>


  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your JavaScript as below:

```
var login_button = $(".checkout-login-button");
var login_form = $(".pop-login-form");
var show_form = false; // add this line
$(document).on('click', '.checkout-login-button', function () {
    if(!show_form){
        //SHOW FORM
        show_form = true;
    }else{
        //HIDE FORM
        show_form = false;
    }
});
```